# Java method calls with different parameter

Tags: java

I have two add methods with argument int and long. When i call "add(2)" , add method with int parameter is called. Can any one help the logic behind this. Why  the other add method is not called.

```
 private static void add(int a){
     System.out.println("int");
 }

  private static void add(long b){
     System.out.println("long");
 }
```

Comment: do you know about overloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's method overloading. When multiple methods having the same name are available, the compiler chooses the method that best fits the supplied parameters.

`2` is a literal of type `int`, so `add(2)` calls the method that takes an `int` argument. To call the method that takes a `long`, call `add(2L)` or `add((long)2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Concept of behind this is **method overloading** which is checked at the compile time, when you pass `int (2)` as argument to method `add` , then it will match the nearest method if multiple methods with `add` is present and match the given param with the best matching method ie which matches the argument list best in terms of .

Read more about method overloading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm.

Answer (score 0):

The number literal `2` is evaluated to be of `int` type *first* if possible. The compiler always tries to make it into `int`. If `int` does not compile, try evaluating it to be of other types.

So here, if you remove the method with the `int` parameter, `2` will be of type `long`. If you remove both overloads and add one that accepts a `double`, `2` will be evaluated to be of type `double`.

If you want to explicitly say you want to call the method that takes `long`, use a long literal like `2L` or `2l`. Alternatively, cast it to a long by `(long)2`.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Java will attempt to treat (whole) numeric literals as int values, therefore the method that expects an int parameter will be invoked.

> Integer Literals
>
> An integer literal is of type long if it ends with the letter L or l;
>   otherwise it is of type int. It is recommended that you use the upper
>   case letter L because the lower case letter l is hard to distinguish
>   from the digit 1.

See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).